# Is moving a canvas considered an inefficient operation as compared to redrawing the whole screen?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Say I have a fullscreen canvas for a bird-view game. When the character move, which operation would be the fastest: redraw the whole background based on a backup canvas or move the canvas's position with css (i.e. style.top = 10)?

Are there any 'taboos' as in moving canvases with DOM operations?

(I understand that moving the canvas would leave a blank space on the sides, but that can be overcome by having smaller canvases that make up the whole background all moving together. Just for the sake of the question, I have reduced the complexity of the problem.)

Comment: If your creating a tile system made up of small canvas elements, rather than moving the tiles you could apply 3d transforms, these are usually hardware accelerated and super fast.

Comment: Here is a good example of CSS 3D -> https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html

Comment: get a small prototype up and running for both ideas, then profile them to see which is slower.

Comment: @Keith I will keep that in mind. What do you think about display:none and removing/adding stuff to the DOM as the player walks off too far? I always imagine that redrawing is 60 times per seconds hard cap while an operation like removing/adding happens once every 5 seconds so it should be the fastest, but I have never seen anybody try this method.

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to animate something with canvas. The proper way to do that is to redraw the whole canvas for each frame and using requestAnimationFrame() to set up a "redraw loop". This way you can achieve 60 fps.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Thanks for the reply. Yes, I assumed that the proper way is to redraw the whole thing and I understand the process, but I thought moving the canvas using DOM properties could be a nice optimization, since I will not need to draw the whole screen each frame. Was just wondering why no one is doing that.